# How to add button to a <div class>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I use the code below in a `<div class="button">Click Me</div>`?

```
button {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I want to transform my boring-looking buttons from `button {` above into the following snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".fancy-button").mousedown(function(){
    $(this).bind('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
     $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
}

.button {
  background: #e74c3c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  height: 65px;
  letter-spacing: .2px;
  line-height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  width: 150px;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #c0392b;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 8px -1px #d7143b;
}

.fancy-button {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.frills, .frills:after, .frills:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: #e74c3c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 8px;
}

.frills:after, .frills:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.frills:before {
  bottom: 45px;
}

.frills:after {
  top: 45px;
}

.left-frills {
  right: 164px;
  top: 28.5px;
}
.active .left-frills {
  -webkit-animation: move-left 0.38s ease-out, width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out;
          animation: move-left 0.38s ease-out, width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out;
}
.left-frills:before, .left-frills:after {
  left: 15px;
}
.active .left-frills:before {
  -webkit-animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-up 0.38s ease-out;
          animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-up 0.38s ease-out;
}
.active .left-frills:after {
  -webkit-animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-down 0.38s ease-out;
          animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-down 0.38s ease-out;
}

.right-frills {
  left: 164px;
  top: 28.5px;
}
.active .right-frills {
  -webkit-animation: move-right 0.38s ease-out, width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out;
          animation: move-right 0.38s ease-out, width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out;
}
.right-frills:before, .right-frills:after {
  right: 15px;
}
.active .right-frills:before {
  -webkit-animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-up 0.38s ease-out;
          animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-up 0.38s ease-out;
}
.active .right-frills:after {
  -webkit-animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-down 0.38s ease-out;
          animation: width-to-zero 0.38s ease-out, move-down 0.38s ease-out;
}

.left-frills:before, .right-frills:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
          transform: rotate(34deg);
}

.left-frills:after, .right-frills:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-34deg);
          transform: rotate(-34deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px);
            transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px);
            transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
}

@keyframes move-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px);
            transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-80px);
            transform: translateX(-80px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
            transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
            transform: translateX(80px);
  }
}
@keyframes move-right {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
            transform: none;
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
            transform: translateX(80px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
            transform: translateX(80px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes width-to-zero {
  0% {
    width: 38px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 8px;
  }
}
@keyframes width-to-zero {
  0% {
    width: 38px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 8px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-up {
  100% {
    bottom: 69.75px;
  }
}
@keyframes move-up {
  100% {
    bottom: 69.75px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-down {
  100% {
    top: 69.75px;
  }
}
@keyframes move-down {
  100% {
    top: 69.75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fancy-button">
  <div class="left-frills frills"></div>
  <div class="button">Ta Da!</div>
  <div class="right-frills frills"></div>
</div>
```

I managed to add the CSS, Html and Script from the CodePen-link above successfully, but only as the *mockup* of the button with no connections to my `button {`). I want the style and the script of the CodePen button to be transferred into my `button {` (my already implemented button already has linked functionalities, I only want this new look and animation)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no minimal, complete markup is shown, it uses markup from a third party link, the question is not quite clear and it's too broad with too many possible answers. [mcve]

Comment: Well, of course I provided a link from *third party* if that can help me explain my questions. Why do you think the "link" functionality is added to the question editor. Internal use? Obviously there is a shortcut to professionalism, because it looks like you went from zero to hero without asking when you got stuck. Like I am. I have done research for many hours but my problem is that I don't know what I should research because I haven't learned this yet.

Comment: It seems you already do all you are asking in the codepen. Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: @Mykita Obviously you have not read what I linked to and still have not provided what is required. If that link goes dead tomorrow, no one will understand your question or any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML is `<div class="button">Click Me</div>`.
The CSS is `button {text-transform: uppercase;}`.
Currently they are not connected because your markup is a **[div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)[.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)** (a div element with a class selector which is button) but your style applies to a **[button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)** element.

So you have two choices

1. change `button{...}` to `.button{...}`
2. or change `<div class="button">Click Me</div>` to `<button>Click Me</button>`

Sorry your question is a bit hard to understand for me but I guess the first choice would be yours - if I only got it right.

## Change CSS | changed `button` to `.button`

```css
.button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Click Me</div>
```

## Change HTML | changed `<div class="button">` to `<button>`

```css
button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

---

*Please feel free to leave a comment if you need any further help.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was just what I was looking for.